# ¿Cómo hacer un `Surface` en un `Surface`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Tengo una superficie azul y quiero crear un rectángulo verde (RGB: 85,107,47) en el centro de la superficie a una distancia de 50 puntos desde el borde del dibujo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import random, sys, pygame, time, copy
from pygame.locals import *
from pygame import Surface

FPS = 30 # frames per second to update the screen
WINDOWWIDTH = 800 # width of the program's window, in pixels
WINDOWHEIGHT = 600 # height in pixels
EARTHWIDTH = 11
EARTHHEIGHT = 1

#              R    G    B
GREEN      = (  85, 107, 47)
BLUE       = ( 70, 130, 180)

TEXTBGCOLOR1 = BRIGHTBLUE
TEXTBGCOLOR2 = GREEN
GRIDLINECOLOR = BLACK
TEXTCOLOR = WHITE
HINTCOLOR = BROWN


def main():
    global MAINCLOCK, DISPLAYSURF, FONT, BIGFONT, BGIMAGE

    pygame.init()
    MAINCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
    DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
    pygame.display.set_caption('TRAVELLER  - LYCEE - NUMERO')
    FONT = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 16)
    BIGFONT = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)

# Background
    drawingSurface = Surface((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
    drawingSurface.fill(BLUE)
    myUpdateRect= pygame.Rect((500, 300), (0, 0))
    BGIMAGE = drawingSurface
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer esta `Surface` en la `Surface`?

Si hay otro camino por recorrer, estoy abierta!

Answer (score 0):

Si he entendido lo que deseas la clave está en usar [`pygame.surface.blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) que básicamente dibuja una imagen sobre otra, dibuja otra surface sobre la propietaria del método.

La firma del método es `blit (source, dest, area = None, special_flags = 0) -> Rect`

- **`source`**: instancia de la surface que va a dibujare encima.
- **`dest`**:  permite posicionar dónde se va a dibujar la surface. Puede ser un iterable con un par de coordenadas que representan la posición de la esquina superior izquierda de la surface o también se puede pasar una instancia de `Rect` en cuyo caso se usa la esquina superior del rectángulo como la posición (el tamaño del rectángulo de destino no afecta a `blit`).
- **`area`**: rectángulo (`Rect`) que representa una porción a dibujar más pequeña de la surface pasada a `source`.
- **`flags`**: permite pasar una serie de banderas especiales a blit como 
  `BLEND_ADD`, `BLEND_SUB`, `BLEND_RGBA_ADD`, `BLEND_RGBA_SUB`, etc

Retorna un rectángulo que representa el área de los píxeles afectados, excluyendo cualquier píxel fuera de la surface de destino o fuera del área de recorte.

Usando dos instancias de `Surface` podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
import sys

import pygame
from pygame.locals import QUIT



FPS = 30 # frames per second to update the screen
WINDOWWIDTH = 800 # width of the program's window, in pixels
WINDOWHEIGHT = 600 # height in pixels
MARGIN_SIZE = (50, 50)

#               R    G    B
GREEN      = ( 85, 107,  47)
BLUE       = ( 70, 130, 180)


def main():
    pygame.init()
    display_surf = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
    pygame.display.set_caption('TRAVELLER  - LYCEE - NUMERO')
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    drawing_surface = pygame.Surface((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
    drawing_surface.fill(BLUE)

    green_surface = pygame.Surface((WINDOWWIDTH - MARGIN_SIZE[0] * 2,
                                    WINDOWHEIGHT - MARGIN_SIZE[1] * 2))
    green_surface.fill(GREEN)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
               pygame.quit()
               sys.exit()

        display_surf.blit(drawing_surface, (0, 0))
        drawing_surface.blit(green_surface, MARGIN_SIZE)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(FPS)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En realidad podrías simplemente rellenar de azul `display_surf` y dibujar encima la Surface verde.